# Screen Editor Error after upgrade to 19.101 - Customization Project Must Be Published

Tags: acumatica

I'm getting a "The customization project must be published before the screen can be edited" error when I try to open a screen in the Screen Editor.  I have 20 screen mods under the Screens node in the customization project.  Only about 6 of them are getting this error.  Some of the screens that are getting the error are completely custom and some are not.

I have upgraded from 18.209 to 19.101.  That is when this started happening.  I am able to open all screens with no problem in 18.209.

I have verified that the page files are in the CstPublished folder of the site.  I also checked the same folder in the validation folder.

The customization project is showing the "published" checkbox as checked.

Has anybody ran into this?  How can I debug?  It looks like there is something that 19.101 doesn't like about these pages.

TIA!

Comment: I've seen it and it looks like it's being investigated at the moment. If this happens on Portal, it is somewhat normal because you shouldn't use the customization editor in portal. Otherwise it is a bug.

Comment: Thanks, HB.  I'm not in the portal; just running this locally.

Comment: There's an hypothesis that new pages placed in Files section that are also in the list of customized screens lead to that error but I'm a bit skeptical about it. The issue remains unresolved it seems.

Comment: We have a high priority case on it but it haven't started.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA do you know if this issue has been fixed?

Comment: It hasn't been fixed. The tentative fix version is 2019R2Preview2, that's all the information I have about it. I'm keeping a close eye on it.

Comment: @HB_ACUMATICA thank you for information, our team has faced the same issue too

Comment: There has been some development. It is now marked as fix but it is not immediately available. It is scheduled to rollout with version Acumatica 2019 R2.

Comment: Is there any temporary fix at the time? I was able to edit my PMProjectEntry page, but after I edited it and published, I can't edit it now.

Comment: This exact issue is currently preventing me from completing work for a client that is attempting to go live at the end of this month. I only experience this issue intermittently, fortunately, and only on some screens, but the features I'm trying to implement are essential for go-live and I'm not sure how to make the error go away like it has in the past. This is a new 19R1 instance. Hopefully a fix comes soon and hopefully it's available for 19R1 as well, and not just 19R2.

Answer (score 1):

We've seen this error before and it turned out to be a dependency/setup issue with a feature that was turned off on the published target company (see Enable/Disable Features).  For example, if you are using a shell company to publish customization projects and your customization references a screen such as Sales Order Entry but the Inventory and Order Management feature is turned off or is not setup this could throw an error upon publish.  We've not necessarily experienced the same problem with previous versions.

Comment: It is confirmed as a known issue in version 2019 and is currently being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message when I tried to add a field, this worked for me:

- Logged out the application.
- Restarted IIS site instance.
- Reloaded site

  Then when i opened the customization screen everything was fine

  PD. My Acumatica version: 5.30.3626